Execute karate script as a scheduled job
Is there a way, we can run scheduled karate scripts?
I have a scenario where my script needs to be executed everyday at 02:00 AM IST.
Can this be done using karate?

No, that should be the responsibility of your CI / CD pipeline.
Nothing prevents you from writing some sort of batch file that starts Karate which can be hooked up to your OS-specific scheduler infra, e.g. cron or Windows Task Scheduler.
